Spring Boot Eager Initialize ConstraintValidator Beans
Why do we see the Spring Beans related to Inbuilt and Custom validators initialized ONLY during the first request. Can this behavior be changed to initialize as part of the application startup in Spring Boot v3.3.2?
[2m2024-08-20T21:44:57.194+04:00[[TRACE[[7332[[2m---[[2m[web-webflux-trace] [nio-8080-exec-1][[2m[66c4d6192e5a47bbf7d8544f82d25b53-f7d8544f82d25b53] [0;39m[36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [[2m:[Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotBlankValidator'
[2m2024-08-20T21:44:57.194+04:00[[TRACE[[7332[[2m---[[2m[web-webflux-trace] [nio-8080-exec-1][[2m[66c4d6192e5a47bbf7d8544f82d25b53-f7d8544f82d25b53] [0;39m[36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [[2m:[Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotBlankValidator'
[2m2024-08-20T21:44:57.194+04:00[[TRACE[[7332[[2m---[[2m[web-webflux-trace] [nio-8080-exec-1][[2m[66c4d6192e5a47bbf7d8544f82d25b53-f7d8544f82d25b53] [0;39m[36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [[2m:[Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.PatternValidator'
[2m2024-08-20T21:44:57.194+04:00[[TRACE[[7332[[2m---[[2m[web-webflux-trace] [nio-8080-exec-1][[2m[66c4d6192e5a47bbf7d8544f82d25b53-f7d8544f82d25b53] [0;39m[36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [[2m:[Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.PatternValidator'


https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33413 Discussed in github

Have you tried creating a custom validator bean using SpringValidatorAdapter? I tested this in one of my apps. Without the custom validator bean, I did see the Hibernate validator bean initialization logs on the first request. Didn't see those logs when I defined a custom validator bean.
Bean definition:
import io.github.devatherock.emailsender.model.EmailSendRequest;

import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter;

@Configuration
public class EmailSenderAppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SpringValidatorAdapter validator() {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        validator.getConstraintsForClass(EmailSendRequest.class);

        return new SpringValidatorAdapter(validator);
    }
}

First request logs without custom validator bean:
2024-10-27 16:12:39,149 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - Before request [POST /email/v1]
2024-10-27 16:12:39,180 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'emailController'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,403 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.AssertTrueValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,404 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.AssertTrueValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,410 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotBlankValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,410 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotBlankValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,411 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.EmailValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,414 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.EmailValidator'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,655 [Aspirin-DeliveryManager-18] INFO  Aspirin  - DeliveryManager started.
2024-10-27 16:12:39,746 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'startupTimeMetrics'
2024-10-27 16:12:39,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - After request [POST /email/v1]

First request logs with custom validator bean:
2024-10-27 16:29:46,429 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - Before request [POST /email/v1]
2024-10-27 16:29:46,455 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'emailController'
2024-10-27 16:29:46,910 [Aspirin-DeliveryManager-18] INFO  Aspirin  - DeliveryManager started.
2024-10-27 16:29:46,975 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'startupTimeMetrics'
2024-10-27 16:29:46,975 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - After request [POST /email/v1]


Thanks a lot @devatherock, this solves the reported problem. However, I do not see in the startup logs as when those ConstraintValidators are loaded. How is the Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator() different from injecting Validator validator?

Those logs are from spring's DefaultListableBeanFactory class. We won't see them anymore as we are skipping dependency injection for the individual validators and letting Hibernate create them.

As discussed on the Spring Framework and Hibernate validation issues, resources available at runtime are really low (100mCPU), so lazy initialization of resources can lead to additional latency for the first request.
Here, you should probably eagerly initialize the loading of constraints with an ApplicationRunner in Spring Boot - such components are executed during startup, before the application declares itself "live" on the liveness endpoint.
As far as I know, Spring cannot automatically detect all the types to be validated in your application at startup. You will have to list as much as you can in a runner, like this:
package io.spring.sample;

import jakarta.validation.Validator;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SampleConfiguratoin {

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner hibernateValidationInitializer(Validator validator) {
        return (args) -> {
            validator.getConstraintsForClass(YourDomainObject.class);
            // other getConstraintsForClass calls...
        };
    }

}



Tried the suggestion, however still bean is getting initialized only on the first call. Could see Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotBlankValidator in TRACE logs
